# Angular custom Validator highlighting field, but not setting <Input>'s invalidity

Tags: angular

I have an angular form using a custom validator. When an invalid value is used it correctly highlights the field in red, but when using @ViewChildren to access the input, it incorrectly shows as valid

How can I get the 's validity as set by the Validator?

My validator's code is

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appThreeDigitsDecimalMax10]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ThreeDigitsDecimalMax10ValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class ThreeDigitsDecimalMax10ValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('appThreeDigitsDecimalMax10') appThreeDigitsDecimalMax10: string;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
        if (!this.appThreeDigitsDecimalMax10) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!control.value || isNaN(control.value)) {
            return { nan: true, valid: false };
        }
        if (control.value >= 0 && control.value < 10) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return { outofrange: true, valid: false };
        }
    }
}
```

[image: field highlighted red] When ran and I input 12 which should fail, it highlights red as expected

My HTML

<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" required #gridInput [appThreeDigitsDecimalMax10]="true">

Then when I grab the inputs `@ViewChildren('gridInput') inputViewChildren !: QueryList<Input>;` and print them out `this.inputViewChildren.forEach(input => { console.log('input', input); ...`, the input's validity shows as true somehow

[image]

How come the input's validity is true? How can I programmatically check the status that's correctly set by the validator, hence the red highlight on the input?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lemme boldly suggest to avoid using template based Angular forms. the reactive forms technology requires a bit more time to master and it's way more powerful and flexible. I would never suggest using template forms for production

Comment: any solution on this? though it's not recommended?

Comment: Don't mess up Angular validation with built-in native web validation

Comment: @yurzui I don't follow?